# How to make sidebar and header fixed using css

Tags: html, css, angular

How do I make my sidebar fixed?

I am using Angular and the `router-outlet` is the component for the page and I want the sidebar and header to not move. What should I add in my css? Here is my code

```html
<div class="whole-page" *ngIf="showSidebar; else login">
      <!--header-->
      <div class="ui top attached demo menu" >
          <a class="item" (click)="sidebar.toggle()">
              <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
          </a>
          <h3>Attendance Management System</h3>
          <div class="right menu">
              <div class="item">User</div>
              <a class="item"><i class="sign out alternate icon"></i></a>
          </div>
      </div>

      <!--sidebar-->
      <sui-sidebar-container class="ui bottom attached segment">
        <sui-sidebar class="inverted vertical" #sidebar>
            <a class="item" routerLink="/attendance-record">Attendance Record</a>
            <a class="item" routerLink="/timestamp-cebu">Timestamp Cebu</a>
        </sui-sidebar>
        <sui-sidebar-sibling [isDimmedWhenVisible]="false">
            <div class="pages">
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </div>
        </sui-sidebar-sibling>
      </sui-sidebar-container>
</div>
```

> Currently, the look of this sidebar is cut as the photo attached

[image]

The only CSS I have is for the `whole-page` class and `pages` class as stated below

```css
.whole-page {
    height: 100%;
}
.pages{
    padding: 30px;    
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this code, hope it works for you.

HTML:

```
<div class="whole-page" *ngIf="showSidebar; else login">
    <!--header-->
    <div class="ui top attached demo menu header" >
        <h3>Attendance Management System</h3>
    </div>
    <!--sidebar-->
    <sui-sidebar-container class="ui bottom attached segment">
        <sui-sidebar class="inverted vertical side-bar" #sidebar>
            <li>
                <a class="item" routerLink="/attendance-record">Attendance Record</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="item" routerLink="/timestamp-cebu">Timestamp Cebu</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="item" routerLink="/attendance-record">Attendance Record</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="item" routerLink="/timestamp-cebu">Timestamp Cebu</a>
            </li>
        </sui-sidebar>
        <sui-sidebar-sibling class="content" [isDimmedWhenVisible]="false">
            <div class="pages">
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
                <p>Hello World</p>
            </div>
        </sui-sidebar-sibling>
    </sui-sidebar-container>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
    height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    z-index: 3;
}

.side-bar{
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: fixed;
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
    top: 60px;
}

.content{
    background: green;
    width: 75%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: this worked for header but for sidebar, it's still cut. Thank you though

Comment: use  `overflow: auto;` in side bar

Answer (score 0):

use below code for fixed header and sidebar also you can change property as per your requirement

```
.ui.bottom {
    position: fixed;
    left: 20px;
    top: 84px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 229px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ui.top {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
     top:0;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: can you please specify where ui bottom and ui top are? what are those classes?

Comment: <div class="ui top attached demo menu" ></div>  <sui-sidebar-container class="ui bottom attached segment"></div>  check both your div

Answer (score 0):

You can create separate components for sidebar and headers. In that way you can use however you want to use them.

I believe this situation is similar to 
[How to use flex-layout in nested components in angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083777/how-to-use-flex-layout-in-nested-components-in-angular-5) this.