# How to use flex-layout in nested components in angular 5?

Tags: html, css, angular, components, angular-flex-layout

I am creating one application which has multiple components using parent child relationship in angular 5.

Inside my main app.component.html I have this structure.

```
        <app-layout-header></app-layout-header>
           <app-layout-view></app-layout-view>
           <app-layout-add></app-layout-add>

           <router-outlet></router-outlet>

        <app-layout-footer></app-layout-footer>
```

where this directive "app-layout-header" is responsible for loading side-navigation and top-navigation like this.

[image: header-with-side-and-top]

Now  this directive "app-layout-view" is responsible for loading data-table or grid like this.

[image]

I want to use flex layout so that I can make it responsive and also I want final result like this.

[image]

But I am not sure how will I place the data-table exactly inside the place I wanted, that is below top-nav-bar and close to side menu. Currently it is coming below the whole side menu as you can see in the second image.

What Should I do now to get desired result?

Comment: You might want to recheck your definition of nested, your example has no nested components, only siblings

Comment: Yes , I misunderstood it. they are sibling components. actually if I am not wrong, The Result HTML is nested. I am not sure how to make it ?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo One solution is to separate app-layout-header Into app-layout-sidebar and app-layout-topbar. In this way I will got clear directive for sidebar as well as top bar and I can put it into clean flex structure. But for that I have to rewrite the app-layout-header.ts file and also need to pass many data through service. Thats a least way I am thinking , Any other solutions that you can suggest?

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-transclusion-using-ng-content

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Wow Thats an amazing concept. I was not at all known to this. Can you please post this as an answer so that I can mark it is correct. Thanks

Comment: No need for it, my comment is not providing a concrete answer to your question, it just hints/suggest a possible one. Furthermore I would strongly suggest to take a look at @angular/material and @covalent/core for examples of navigation drawers.

Comment: That's so nice of you. Now I am getting desired result using transclusion in my app.  I am using @angular/material for drawers. @covalent/core is again a superb thing that you have introduced to me. I will surly check it out and use it in my project. Thanks you :-)