# Enabling relative and flex to be shared across angular components

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular6, angular2-components

So I have one component like so;

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container"> 
<external-component></external-component>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-container{
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
display: flex;
position: relative;
}
```

CSS for external component

```
.external{
flex: 1 1 50%;
height: 20vh;
background-color:black;
}
```

This doesn't work however it will display nothing, I'm assuming that for some reason the external component doesn't appear to inherit from the parent element.

Any work arounds for this would be fantastic.

Comment: Can you describe your file structure a little bit? Want to see how you organize the components and import it.

Comment: The reason is `flex` only applies to **immediate** children, and therefore anything within `external-component` is no longer an immediate child. What browsers do you need to support?

Comment: Ideally all browsers would be great, and the file structure is your standard Angular 6/7 structure I generate everything using ng g c .... And this particular component resides within the app.component.html if that helps?

- Edit all modern versions of the browsers that is.

Comment: Maybe take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083777/how-to-use-flex-layout-in-nested-components-in-angular-5

Comment: The transclusion aspect might do the trick cheers for that.

Comment: May be @user184994 write his answer (and develop a little) and Munerz accept that answer?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Not my answer, it's just pointing to a duplicate question

Comment: The flex-container will only affect 'external-component', if you want the items of ''external-component" to be flex-items too, you'll have to add it in "external-component.css"

Comment: you probably need the css selector to be `:host` instead of `.external` for the `external-component` css

Answer (score 0):

Either add a css class `external` in `app.component.html` to the `<external-component/>` and move styles for external to app.component.css, or rename the class `.external` to `:host`.  Or move all these styles into `styles.css` (which is not scoped to any specific component).

So, solution 1:

```
<div class="flex-container"> 
  <external-component class="external"></external-component>
</div>
```

That, and styles are all in *app.component.css*.

Solution 2, *external.component.css*:

```
.external{
  flex: 1 1 50%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color:black;
}
```